# Construction of “woe is me”

Tags: idioms, grammatical-case, old-english, be

The expression “woe is me” ([meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296656/woe-is-me-what-does-it-mean)) looks strange. On the surface, it seems to mean “an unhappy event is me”. Sure, it's an old idiom, undoubtedly reflecting vocabulary or grammar that is no longer productive in modern English. But what old language feature does it reflect? Is *woe* used as an adjective which is the complement of the verb and *me* an inverted subject (in which case, why isn't it “woe am I”)? Or does it mean “misery is me”, as in, “misery fills my soul so that I am misery personified”? I understand “woe betide me” (ok, not the most common object) and “woe [is] unto me”, but “woe is me” puzzles me.

[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/04/woes-by-any-other-name.html) states that *woe* is the subject, but it isn't clear how the rest of the sentence is constructed. As a shortening or evolution of “woe is unto me”? How did that happen?

Comment: Potentially related (I haven't read all the answers): [Why do we use the object instead of the subject pronoun in constructions like “stupid me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woe is me - what does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296656/woe-is-me-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: @HotLicks The other question was asking for the meaning; this one for the underlying old language feature it reflects. How are those the same?

Comment: @HotLicks Uh? As I have stated in my question, I am aware of that thread, it asked a related but different question and the answers, including yours, do not extend to answering my question. In what possible way can it be a duplicate?

Comment: Miscellaneous side note: there's a grammar book titled _Woe is I: The Grammarphobe's Guide to Better English in Plain English_, which dedicates its first chapter to pronoun agreement. The relevant line from that book is _"Hundreds of years after the first Ophelia cried "Woe is me," some pedants would argue that Shakespeare should have written 'Woe is I' or 'Woe is unto me.' (Never mind that the rules of English grammar weren't even formalized in Shakespeare's day.)"_

Comment: Your suggestion of "misery is me" is always how I've taken it, "woe" being interpreted as an emotional state of misery and despair.  It never occured to me to interpret "woe" to mean "an unhappy event"; I'm not sure I've heard it used in such a way in other contexts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is indeed old, and can be found in Beowulf:

> **Wa** bið þæm þe sceal þurh sliðne nið sawle bescufan in fyres fæþm, frofre ne wenan, wihte gewendan; **wel** bið þæm þe mot æfter deaðdæge drihten secean ond to fæder fæþmum freoðo wilnian.
>
> **Woe** be to him who through severe affliction thrust his soul into the fire’s embrace, hope not for relief, or to change at all; **Well** be to him who after his death may seek the Lord and long for peace in the Father’s arms.
>
> <sub>[“Woe to the Rich and the Sordid Fellows”: The Syntax,
> Semantics and Information Structure of ‘Woe’ in
> Indo-European](http://org.uib.no/iecastp/IECASTP/Woe.pdf)</sub>

Note the emphasis (which is from the cited paper). *Woe* here is parallel to *well*; because *well* is an adverb, so is *woe*.

(Note: In this particular sense, "Wa bið þæm" is closest in meaning to "Cursed is he".)

The OED explains that this usage came from the interjection *woe* (which was a "common Indo-European interjection" also used in OE):

> Arising as an adverbial use of the interjection with the dative, although in later use probably often interpreted as a noun

Comment: I don't know why you say that it’s “closest in meaning” to “Cursed is he”, given that “Cursed is he” is a reversed copula equivalent to “He is cursed”. (The first-person version would be “Cursed am I”.) Whereas “Wa bið þæm” clearly uses *þæm*, which was just as much of an object form as *them* or *me* still is today. Wouldn’t “A curse unto him” be closer?

Comment: @tchrist Because that's what it's translated as in some translations, like [this one](https://www.shmoop.com/beowulf/lines-1-300-quotes-4.html). It's also what OED says. It's probably translated this way because prescriptivist grammar says so.

Comment: You are saying that 'well' is an adverb in say 'he is well'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, that’s not what’s being asserted here. You should read the referenced paper. Start towards the bottom of p. 4 et seqq for the discussion of this having been originally an adverb. In Old English, *wel* was strictly an adverb of the positive degree, *bet* of the comparative, and *best* of the superlative. The adjectival senses you’re thinking of in Modern English are much newer. If you still have some Latin, they also present the evidence that *vae* — as in the familiar “Vae victis!” (woe to the vanquished) — cannot have been a noun either. Strange, I know; you should read it.

Comment: @tchrist Laurel should define terms if using them in a non-standard (by today's standards) way.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, English has (in many cases) "before-the-verb and after-the-verb constructs. "Who's that at the door?" is usually answered by "It's me," rather than "It is I." "Me" (much more than "he" or "she") behaves a bit like the French "moi."

Also "he," "she," and "me," rhyme for whatever that's worth.